# How to add sounds to questions or answers here

Tags: support

If I wanted add a sequence of sounds to an answer on the role of temperament in the mood produced by different keys how would I do that? I'm looking for the best way of embedding a sequence of (perhaps polyphonic) tones of specific frequencies into a Musical Practise & Performance SE question or answer, not as notation but rendered as sound?